# Unable to get $file from Modal element, Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using a modal element that prompts users to select a file to upload to a site and I can't seem to get the file.  Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="modal-section align-left">
      <input type="file" accept='application/pdf' ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" file></input>
 </div>
```

and here is the javascript I'm trying to use to get it:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = ($file);
```

It seems like it should be a simple enough task but something isn't connecting and I'm not sure what.  I keep getting a '$file is not defined' error.

Any thoughts would be helpful! Thanks!

Just realized that I should also mention that I was using cheynewallace's code on git hub which can be found here: https://github.com/cheynewallace/angular-s3-upload
 to try and get my modal element to send the selected file to Amazon Web Services.  I got the version he put up to work but for whatever reason, I can't get it to work with modal elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be mixing up two directives. ng-file-select comes from [danialfarid's angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) while the file directive is from [cheynewallace's example](https://github.com/cheynewallace/angular-s3-upload/blob/master/js/directives.js) you mentioned.

If you are going with cheynewallace's, then you are probably missing his directive (linked above). Looking at the code, his directive only supports a single file upload and sets the file to a $scope.file variable. In his example, he uses:

```
<input type="file" file></input>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" ng-click="upload()">Upload</a>
```

Your controller would need to be something like this:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.upload = function() {
        // do something with $scope.file
    };
});
```

If you are going with danialfarid's directive, then you can remove the `file` attribute from your input. This would leave you with:

```
<input type="file" accept='application/pdf' ng-file-change="onFileSelect($files)"></input>
```

And your controller would need to look something like this:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
        // do something with $files
    };
});
```

**warning** I have not tested these two approaches, but I believe either will get you on the write track.

---

**Update**

[Here's a working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ubIhgrHuU8TVqXcRY8hA). I just made a quick concrete example with my code above, but my first snippet was wrong about the `ng-file-change`. It should have been `ng-file-select` like you had initially. The plunk illustrates both directives. I also added the `ng-multiple='true'` attribute in the danialfarid example to allow multiple file selection.

Comment: Thanks bbennett! You are correct, I looked into it and it looks like these are two separate directives.  I'll give this a try and see what comes of it.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer if you are satisfied? I need some cred :)

Comment: I'm just testing it out both ways you suggested...then I'll mark it ;)

Comment: I think that it's the two directives being used at once that is making this difficult and although I couldn't get it to work, I'm pretty sure you are correct in that they are conflicting with each other. Thanks again!

Comment: Couldn't leave you hanging. I updated my answer with a working example.

Comment: You're a saint! Thank you! :D